# Not iterable argument

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to extract a list of names (column 1) which have 'good' in their descriptions (column 2) from an excel by the following code, but I keep recieving this Error:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

```
import openpyxl
import os
import pprint
os.chdir('C:\\')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
row = 1
names = {}
while True:
    (name, description) = (sheet.cell(row, 1).value, sheet.cell(row, 2).value)
    nameCheck = 'good' in description
    if name == None:
        break
    if nameCheck:
        names[name] = description
    row = row + 1
pprint.pprint(names)
```

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Comment: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because description returns the value None in runtime at the end. You just check if name==None and not description but the line nameCheck= 'good' in description returns None at the end and that is why you get the Nonetype error. To resolve this, use an if condition for the description variable too. Refer the following code.

```
import openpyxl
import os
import pprint
os.chdir('C:\\')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
row = 1
names = {}
while True:
    (name, description) = (sheet.cell(row, 1).value, sheet.cell(row, 2).value)
    if description is not None:
        nameCheck = 'good' in description
        if nameCheck:
            names[name] = description
    if name == None:
        break
    row = row + 1
pprint.pprint(names)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But we have names that do not have any description, so with this code program skipps the rest of the list when it comes to such names. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem but I don't know if my understanding of the problem is right or not.
In the code you should only define nameCheck in this way:
nameCheck = 'good' in str(description)
Actually 'description' in "description = sheet.cell(row, 2).value" is not string which could be iterated! So by changing its type to string we can turn it to iterable type.